# Selecting random arrays from multidimensional numpy array with replacement

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional ndarray and I'm looking to randomly select 1000 arrays WITH replacement.  This seem to me to be simple, but the with replacement part I'm struggling to incorporate.

There are 3065 arrays in this ndarray.

```
np.shape(train_spam)
(3065L, 58L)
```

I tried to use np.random.shuffle() but this does not take into account the with replacement.

```
np.random.shuffle(train_spam)
X_train = train_spam[:1000,1:57]
```

My final output would have ea shape of (1000L, 58L).

I suppose I could run a loop with a ndarray with

```
X_train = train_spam[0:57]
```

and then append but I can't figure out how to append correctly, so it looks the same.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is this problem specific to numpy? If all you need is a general way to select random arrays with replacement, I suggest `selection = [arrays[random.randrange(n)][:] for i in range(k)]` where `n` is the size of `arrays` and `k` is the number of elements you want to select with replacement.

Comment: If that suits your needs, please let me know and I'll post a formal answer.

Comment: actually did not work for me, i'm trying to get better at numpy though, to answer your question

Comment: I took a look at the numpy docs a minute ago. There's an ndarray method called `choose()`. Does this work for you? `train_spam.choose([random.randrange(3065) for i in range(1000)])`

Comment: thanks for the help,  i got this error:  TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'

Comment: I gather that one or both indices in the expression should be long. How about this? `train_spam.choose([long(random.randrange(3065)) for i in range(1000L)])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
selected = train_spam[np.random.randint(train_spam.shape[0], size=1000)]
```

Comment: The `0` argument is unnecessary though. `np.random.randint(train_spam.shape[0], size=1000)` will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can also build a list of indices with `[random.randrange(n) for i in range(k)]`.

```
k = 1000                                           # Number of elements to select.
n = train_spam.shape[0]                            # Number of elements in array.
indices = [random.randrange(n) for i in range(k)]  # A plain Python list.
selected = train_spam[np.array(indices)]           # Convert indices to ndarray.
```

If you have a plain Python list from which you want to select elements with replacement, you can do this:

```
pets = ['ant', 'bear', 'cat', 'dog', 'elephant', 'flamingo', 'gorilla', 'horse']
n = len(pets)
k = 10
selected = [pets[random.randrange(n)] for i in range(k)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain multiple arrays randomly from ndarray, Using Random Generator.

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4], [5,6,7]])
rng = np.random.default_rng()
rng.choice(a, 2)
```